# Passing a key-value array in NodeJS for MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, select

I can pass an array to an mysql insert in nodeJS like so..

```
var data = {userId: 3, name: "sample"}       
db.query('insert into my_table SET ?', data, function(err, result){...}
```

Is there a similar way of passing an array to a select query in the where clause... without specifying all the fields?

```
var data = {userId: 3, name: "sample"} 
db.query('select * from my_table WHERE ?', data, function(err, result){...}
```

Doesn't seem to work.. nor does using the SET name in place of where...

Answer (score 0):

```
database.conn.config.defaultQueryFormat = function (query, values) {

if (!values) return query;
var updatedQuery = query.replace("?", function () {    
var whereClause = "";  
for(var index in values){
  whereClause += mysql.escapeId(index) + " = " + db.escape(values[index]) + " and ";
}

whereClause = whereClause.substring(0, whereClause.length - 5);

return whereClause;
});

return updatedQuery;
};
```

This appears to work.. e.g.
var val = db.query('select * from my_table where ?', data, function(err, result) {
}